# Blender alternative tool for 'cut faces tool' of Maya

Tags: modeling, mesh

I recently watched a [Maya tutorial](https://youtu.be/KlpYouGtvZA), (Time- 7:47) where a cylinder is cut diagonally using cut faces tool.

I am wondering is there a similar tool that exists in blender?

With the Knife tool I cannot diagonally cut/slice the whole circumference of a cylinder.

Comment: Use the Z key (cut through) during the knife operation (available keys/options are shown in the status bar during the cut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the *[knife tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife.html#knife-tool)* in blender.
Shortcut <kbd>K</kbd> by default. You have to be in *edit mode* to use it.

[image]